# Using PyVimeo error 404 when create a live event

Tags: django, vimeo, pyvimeo

I am just starting the integration of vimeo on my web platform for lives (I have a premium account)

Currently, the client connects well with this code:

```
vimeo.VimeoClient(token=settings.VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN,key=settings.VIMEO_CLIENT_ID,secret=settings.VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET)
```

Until then, no worries.

Then I do a test to create a live with the following code:

```
uri = '/me/live_events'
response= client.post(uri, data={'title':'test from api'})
```

And I have a 404 feedback, I also did the test directly from vimeo with message :

[image: response]

Note that the only two fields required are client_id and title.

And my scopes token :

[image]

I don't see where my mistake may be

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live API access is only available to Vimeo Enterprise users. It is not open to Premium users:

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042881411-Live-API-access